# Where can I create images from? Locally at all? (Docker remote API)

Tags: image, api, docker

May/may not be an easy question here, but where can I pull images from to create a new docker image via the API?

[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21/#create-an-image)

My (unsuccessful) attempts have been trying to build an image from something local. Using `docker images` to get a list of images, then trying to use their Image ID or Repository has not worked for me while using the `fromImage` query param like so:

`curl --data '' host:port/images/create?fromImage=test/hello-world&tag=webTesting`

I consistently get the following error:

`{"errorDetail":{"message":"Error: image test/hello-world not found"},"error":"Error: image test/hello-world not found"}`

In running `docker images`, we can very clearly see the following:

`REPOSITORY         TAG     IMAGE ID      CREATED     VIRTUAL SIZE
 test/hello-world   latest  6d9bd5e6da4e  2 days ago  556.9 MB`

In all combinations of using the repository/tag/id the error still displays. I understand that we can create images from urls with `fromSrc`, and there are alternative create image routes by uploading .tar files, but **is it possible in the case to create an image from one that already exists locally?** I've had success in compiling images from ubuntu or centos, but I'm looking basically to replicate something local with new tags/repository.

I do see in the documentation that fromImage parameter may only be used when pulling an image -- **does this mean we can only import images that are hosted on Dockerhub?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, the Docker [remote API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21/#create-an-image) clearly states that a pull operation must be triggered for this image reference.

This does not require that you use DockerHub, but it means that the image must be located on a registry and not simply in your daemon's *local cache*. If you were running a Docker registry instance on your host (which is easily done with the [public registry image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/) in DockerHub) on port 5000, then you could use "**localhost:5000/test/hello-world**" as the `fromImage`, and it will pull it from your locally hosted registry (after you push it locally of course).

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. I set up a [local registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) and was quickly pushing/pulling images locally -- Thanks!